# Door jamb wider than framed entry

Tags: wood, doors, framing, door-frame, hinges

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for this issue I ran into. So I have a door jamb that sits at 79.5" wide and the actual frame is at 79.25" wide.

I have 3 options:

1. trim either the hinge or doorknob side down. Cons: Weakens either the hinge frame side or the passage latch will have to feed into the wall stud in the frame.
2. trim the frame entry, Cons: harder to do, chances wont be a clean cut, thou can be hidden
3. take 1/4" off the top of the door frame and door itself

I cant decide which one I should do. Would love some advice on what you thoughts around this are.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could give you some easy tips on adjusting the door and jamb but I would only do that if there wasn't the option to - **make the frame bigger (rough opening)**.

You can plane off 1/4" on one of the sides in about 5-10 minutes and you won't be messing with the integrity of the door you bought.   You can plane sloppy and with shims you are still good to go.

Comment: I agree, and I'd set a circular saw to 1/2" depth and make cross-cuts every half an inch. A few taps with a chisel and you have a nice flat plane again.

Comment: @isherwood - yes have done that too.   But I can only get the electric planer out a few times a month and with the ability to use it and not have to be perfect I would rather play with my toys but good alternative for someone without a planer.

Comment: Yeah, most folks won't have one, and that's actually quite a bit of material to move with a planer. You'll have a heck of a gerbil habitat when you're done.

Comment: Mine does 1/8" on highest setting - that is just three swipes.   5 minutes if there are no nails in the way.   If I can see the nails I use a nail setter to dig them in deeper and run the planer through and repeat.   When sawing the nails sometimes just get cut and sometimes they become a huge hassle.   Also if you do bump a nail on one side you can go to the other side when planing or take of 3/16" on each side or whatever.

Comment: I didnt think of using a chisel, thats definitely an option and I most likely going to use. I guess if integrity was a bigger issue, I could just take off an 1/8th on each side. But this is way more consumable than other options

Comment: @AaronBakker once you get into making that door smaller you need expertise.   I could do it because I have retrofitted doors 10xs of times over.   But damn straight I messed up a few times on my first batches.   Not only that but even with experience, this way is quicker.

Comment: It would be wise to find if the original rough opening is actually plumb to start with. That way the cuts made to make it bigger can also be used to make the opening plumb by taking more off the top or bottom as needed.

Comment: @Jack - great point something I take for granted... something I always forget to tell my crew when I am not doing it.... we use a lot of shims!

Comment: @Jack - think about this too.   If something is really out of whack.   What excellent practice for your planing skills.   I am up for it right now - give me a board 1/2" out of square and let me get it pretty damn close while I shave off enough for the frame.

Comment: @DMoore I chiseled off the 1/4" yesterday but its still a hair too big, looks like I get to break out the belt sander today. The frame was plume, luckily, I did check that to start, at least the previous owner did something right. This isnt the first retro fit Ive had to make with this house.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would trim off the latch side of the door, and reduce the width of the jamb appropriately.  There are ways that can reinforce that part of the door if needed, but it would be more difficult to reinforce the hinge side which is where most of the forces are.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to trim the door on the hinge side. Why? Why the door and not the frame? Easier, cleaner, can remove the door to work on, much harder to work on the frame in place or reinstall the frame. Why the hinge side and not the latch side? For the very simple reason that the door latch is not adjustable and set by the distance of the hole for the knobs. If you trim that side of the door, the latch will be in the same place and 'proud' (sicking out) of the new door surface. Moving the drilled hole is a very difficult proposition to say the least. On the hinge side, all you have to do is deepen the hinge pockets the same amount that you trim the door. And you have the existing hinge pocket edges as a guide. And if go too far, it's easy to fix with shimming. And it's in an relatively hidden area.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a solid hard wood door trimming from the door would be the easiest way to go but if it is not one solid piece of wood by all means go for the rough opening.